# JavaScript convert array to counter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to know how to convert a one-dimensional array into a frequency dictionary with the elements of the array as keys, and their occurrences as values, in JavaScript.

For example, the following Python script creates a list of 1024 random numbers between 0 and 255 and counts the elements as described:

```py
import random
from collections import Counter

sorted(Counter(random.randbytes(1024)).items(), key=lambda x: -x[1])
```

I can do the same in JavaScript, but much less concise:

```js
var numbers = Array.from({length: 1024}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256))
var counter = Object()

for (let number of numbers) {
    if (counter.hasOwnProperty(number)) {counter[number] += 1}
    else {counter[number] = 1}
}

Object.entries(counter).sort(([,a],[,b]) => b-a)
```

How do I make it more concise?

Comment: Why don't you think your approach is efficient? Or do you mean you'd just like the code to be more concise?

Comment: @AndrewParks I can be wrong, but OP probably means "less lines of code", which obviously doesn't signify more time — or memory — efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This surprised me: on my Mac, the Map version took 2.7s, and the Object version took 0.6s when testing with 100 million numbers.

(Your original version takes the same time as the Object version in the code below)

```js
const numbers = Array.from({length:10**8},()=>Math.random()*256|0)

let timerStart = new Date()
{
  let counter = new Map()
  numbers.forEach(n=>counter.set(n,(counter.get(n)??0)+1))
  counter = new Map([...counter].sort(([,a],[,b]) => b-a))
}

console.log(`Map version took ${new Date()-timerStart} ms`)


timerStart = new Date()
{
  let counter = numbers.reduce((a,c)=>(a[c]=(a[c]??0)+1,a),{})
  Object.entries(counter).sort(([,a],[,b]) => b-a)
}

console.log(`Object version took ${new Date()-timerStart} ms`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ES6 one-liner to solve the problem, using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and the fact that the value of a [comma separated list of expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) is the value of the last one:

```js
const numbers = Array.from({length: 1024}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256))

const counter = numbers.reduce((acc, num) => (acc[num] = (acc[num] || 0) + 1, acc), {})

const sorted = Object.entries(counter).sort(([,a],[,b]) => b-a)

console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a Map:

```js
var numbers = Array.from({length: 1024}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256))

const map = numbers.reduce((accum, d) => accum.set(d, (accum.get(d) || 0) + 1), new Map());
```

Comment: This code doesn't actually work. Have you tried `console.log(map)` at the end of it?

Answer (score 0):

A quick "improvement" would be to use the ternary statement to make the code more concise.

```
var numbers = Array.from({length: 1024}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256))
var counter = Object()

for (let number of numbers) {
    //If counter has prop number, increment it by one otherwise set to 1
    counter.hasOwnProperty(number) ? counter[number]++ : counter[number] = 1;
   //Alternatively 
   //counter[number] = counter.hasOwnProperty(number) ? counter[number] + 1 : 1
}

Object.entries(counter).sort(([,a],[,b]) => b-a)
```